# onGoing notification disappears after a few second

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am trying to put a notification in the status bar when a service starts and keep it there until I stop the service but is disappears after a few seconds(about 10). Any suggestions as to what I am missing? This worked before I tried to re write using notification.builder for compatibility with api 15. The log entry shows onDestroy is not called until I stop the service so it is still running.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private int NOTIFICATION = R.string.service_started;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    showNotification();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("MyService", "Service Started");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
    Log.e("MyService", "Service Ended");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private void showNotification() {

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setAutoCancel(false)
           .setOngoing(true)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myicon)
           .setTicker(getText(R.string.service_label))
           .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
           .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.service_started))
           .setContentText(getText(R.string.service_label));
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
```

Comment: Is your service getting destroyed for some reason? I see in the onDestroy you remove your notification.  Where do you call showNotification()?

Comment: Sorry, I must have edited that line out when pasting the question. showNotification gets called in onCreate. The log entry displayed in onDestroy is only shown when I end the service with stopService, the notification just disappears after around 10 seconds and the service is still running.

Comment: Should add that this worked as expected with setLatestEventInfo which is depreciated and I am trying to rewrite with notification.builder

Comment: I seem to be getting some odd behavior with this notification. Sometime the notification is created to the left of the usb debugging / usb connected notifications and when it is it stays and other times it is created to the right of them and then disappears after a few seconds. seems fairly random though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with an ongoing notification disappearing in ICS on a new phone. The app and notification had worked perfectly in every version of Android I had tested it on previously, and it even works on an ICS emulator. Needless to say this has been driving me crazy for a couple months now, but I finally found the answer.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21635

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to monitor incoming calls on the handset and I programmatically enable the receiver when a button is toggled in addition to setting the notification. So I wrote a small test app with the same BroadcastReceiver hooked up and was able to reproduced the problem. I commented out the setComponentEnabledSetting call and the notification no longer disappears.